# Django: Having trouble with users uploading files, and updating records in the db

Tags: python, django

For my django project, I am using a custom user model, and this works just fine. I also have a page that lets a user edit their own profile, and this also works correctly.

I just added an ImageField field to my user model for an avatar image. However I am having trouble with letting the user update the image themselves. It works fine in the admin interface, but not my user form.

Here is the relevant part models.py

```
# Generates the path for uploaded avatar images
def upload_avatar_path(instance, filename):
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return 'user/{0}/avatar.{1}'.format(instance.username, ext)


# Users
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Custom user model for amvl.
    """
    username = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        max_length=50,
    )

    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_avatar_path,
        default='user/default.png'
    )

    bio = models.TextField()


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['avatar', 'bio']
```

As you can see, the form  am using for a user to edit their profile is a ModelForm.

Here is the views.py

```
def profile_edit(request, profile):
    # Check if logged in user is the same as the profile edit page
    if request.user.username == profile:
        profile = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        # If this is a form submission
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                try:
                    update = ProfileUpdateForm(
                        request.POST,
                        request.FILES,
                        instance=profile,
                    )
                    update.save()
                    return HttpResponse("UPDATED")
                except:
                    return HttpResponse('FAILED')
        else:
            form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)
            context = {
                'form': form,
            }
            return render(request, 'user/profile_edit.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("NOT ALLOWED")
```

Everything works correctly here, except for updating the avatar field. Interestingly, when I submit the form "UPDATED" is returned, indicating that it worked. But when I check, the avatar image is *not* updated, even if other fields are.

Other examples I've seen seem to suggest that I need to use `request.FILES['avatar']` to save the record, but when I do, it returns "FAILED".

When I remove the `try` and `except` statements to view the debug info, its shows a `MultiValueDictKeyError at /user/admin/edit/`, `"'avatar'"`. (When I use `request.FILES['avatar']`)

Comment: Have you tried not catching the exception when using `request.FILES['avatar']` to see what Django complains about?

Comment: **Never** catch a blank exception. We and you have no idea what is going wrong, because you're hiding all the useful information that Django will be giving you. Remove all that and let's see what is actually happening.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that, I've updated the original post. I was checking the debug info before, I just didn't put it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django documentation for [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/), and since you’re working with a `ModelForm`, you should use:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
```

#### In case you’re not using a `ModelForm`…

…but you’re building one of your own, use:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = User(avatar=request.FILES['avatar'])
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
```

Now, if it still raises a `MultiValueDictKeyError` (I’m actually not sure of which to give to the key), try catching the exception to get the keys of `request.FILES`:

```
try:
    instance = User(avatar=request.FILES['avatar'])
except MultiValueDictKeyError:
    raise KeyError('Keys for `request.FILES` are {}'.format(request.FILES.keys()))
```

Comment: As for your first block of code, yes, I've seen that, and my code is essentially the same. However, I believe that this code will create a _new_ entry in the database, not update a current one. That's what `instance=profile` is for in my code. And as for the second part, it may help other people who find this question, but not me.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. It had nothing to do with my python code or Django, my HTML form was missing it's `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.